# How to use Synchronize()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, c++builder

The manual says that Synchronize is a member of TThread.
However it shows that you can call Synchronize directly. Other [sources](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30382&seqNum=6) tell the same.

```
//Synchronize() performs actions contained in a routine as if they were executed from the main VCL thread    

void __fastcall TCriticalThread::Execute()
{
   ...
   Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
   ...
}
```

But if I do this, my compiler tells me "E2268 Call to undefined function 'Synchronize'". Of course I included the library:

```
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
```

---

On the other hand, TThread::Synchronize is found by the compiler, but it does not accept MainThreadID as parameter:

```
TThread::Synchronize(MainThreadID, MainForm->UpdateCaption );
```

---

PS: I am new to C++ Builder.

Comment: Show definition of your `TCriticalThread` class. Is it a descendant of `TThread`?

Comment: @MBo - that was just one piece of code that I took from "other sources" (see link) to show that the Embarcadero documentation AND other sources tell us that we should be able to call Synchronize directly.

Comment: We definitely are able to call Synchronize directly from body of method belonging to TThread descendant. That is why I was interested in class description. Real code, please.

Comment: I am in a callback function, in a DLL. The working thread is calling this callback function every few ms.

Comment: Calling `TThread::Synchronize()` inside a DLL *WILL NOT* call the specified method in the UI thread of the calling application, unless 1) your DLL is a BPL runtime package that shares a common instance of the RTL with the app or 2) your DLL exports a function that calls the RTL's `CheckSynchronize()` function, and then the app calls that exported DLL function periodically in its UI thread. `Synchronize()` stores the method pointer in an internal queue, which `CheckSynchronize()` processes, and that queue is not shared with the app when the app and DLL are compiled with separate RTL instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Synchronize()` is a method of the RTL's `TThread` class.  In all versions of C++Builder, `TThread` has a non-static version of `Synchronize()`, which is the version the code you showed is trying to call.  That requires `TCriticalThread` to be derived for `TThread`, eg:

```
class TCriticalThread : public TThread
{
...
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall Execute();
...
};

void __fastcall TCriticalThread::Execute()
{
   ...
   Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
   ...
}
```

If that is not the case in your situation, `TThread` also has a static version of `Synchronize()` that can be used with threads that are not derived from `TThread`, eg:

```
void __fastcall TCriticalThread::Execute()
{
   ...
   TThread::Synchronize(NULL, UpdateCaption);
   ...
}
```